# Leaky expansion tank overflow

Tags: furnace, leak, overflow

I have a gas fired furnace with forced hot water. Off of the expansion tank there is a drain pipe. Recently it started leaking, roughly a mason jar a day. 
Why is this happening and can I solve the issue?

---

[image]

Tank is right above and next to boiler

Comment: Pictures would help. If it's a bladder/sealed type tank, possibly a bladder failure. Normally an open expansion tank is at the highest point in the house (or at least above the highest radiator) and is somewhat antique, so less likely.

Comment: Is the expansion tank mounted near the boiler or is it  mounted in an upper floor of the house, maybe in a cupboard or in the attic? It makes a difference.

Comment: Welcome to the site James. Please use the "edit" button when updating your question rather than posting in the "answer" section. Posting responses as answers can result in an [automated lock](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) that can prevent others from assisting you.